# Web application inside website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service, azure-vm-role

I'm seeking some guidance for hosting websites on azure. 
I have a **Umbraco website**, which work fine on azure website.
I also have an **MVC application** I want to host inside my umbraco site, but it has to be run as an application.

This work fine in IIS by converting the folder to a application, but there is no option to do this on azure.

Is there a easy way to convert the folder to a application inside my umbraco solution or do I have to create a virtual machine with web roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more control than just creating an [**Azure Website**](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/web-sites/) - you need to create an [**Azure VM**](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) or use an [**Azure Web Role**](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/cloud-services/) hosted service.